# Nested NSAttributedString (s)

Tags: swift

I am producing a PDF Invoice from my Swift app. Because not all address patched will be the same depth I am using carriage returns to layout the text. Address, Date, Invoice Number, Subject line and narrative, for example. it all works really well, however, I want to format the Subject line in bold text. I have looked all around this subject and drawn a blank. In essence my question is can you nest NSAttributed Strings, so that I can format the subjectline in Bold without having to create another NSAttributed String which would mean loosing my layout discipline?

This is my code

```
    let textFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0, weight: .regular)
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .natural
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
                          NSAttributedString.Key.font: textFont,
                          NSAttributedString.Key.kern : -0.15] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

    let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "\(billAddress)\r\r\r\("Invoice number:  \ . 
     (invoiceNumber)")\r\("Date:  \(mydate)")\r\r\r\("To")\r\r\(subjectline)\r\r\(narrative)", 
    attributes: 
    textAttributes as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any])
```

Any help/ideas/solution would be welcome

Comment: By the way, you can use multi-line string literals to get rids of all the `\r` madness

Comment: Use a NSMutableAttributedString, and append instead of trying to do it in one go. Example: https://pastebin.com/qDWLZxV4

Comment: What are multiline string literals and how will they maintain the design and typographic discipline as indicated in my question - thank you though

Comment: Thank you Larne - really useful but has shot the layout to to the wall. How can I reinstate the line break discipline? Thank you once again

Comment: Thank you again Larme - this is what I ended up with and work/looks great

Comment: It would be much simpler to create a HTML template in an external file and convert it to `NSAttributedString`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSMutableAttributedString`, and append different parts of string using `.append(_:)` method. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring/1417879-append)

Also you can take a look at https://github.com/Rightpoint/BonMot

Comment: As I understand it the .append solution involves using range to define the characters to append - since the subject line will be variable how will this help me. I did look at that option. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .natural
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    let defaultAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
                                                            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0, weight: .regular),
                                                            NSAttributedString.Key.kern : -0.15]

    let boldAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
                                                         NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0, weight: .bold),
                                                         NSAttributedString.Key.kern : -0.15]
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString()

    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: (billAddress), attributes: defaultAttributes))
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\r\r"))
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Invoice number:  \(invoiceNumber)", attributes: defaultAttributes))
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\r"))
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Date:  \(mydate)", attributes: defaultAttributes))
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\r\r"))
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "To", attributes: defaultAttributes))
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\r\r"))
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: subjectline, attributes: boldAttributes))
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\r"))
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: narrative, attributes: defaultAttributes))

    let textRect = CGRect(x: 40, y: textTop, width: pageRect.width - 240,
                          height: pageRect.height - textTop - pageRect.height / 2 )
    attributedText.draw(in: textRect)
```